# How to get parameters from a url?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

I have this URL: `http://example.com/photos/5062d95d-13e8-ceb8-bb35-5891b62a3418/?id=872364876`

And I have this javascript code:

```
if (sssssssssss) {
    window.location = "http://example.com/s/1525";
} else {
    location.replace('http://example.com/id=');
}
```

I need to fill the `id` value from the GET parameters in the `else` section. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to get variables from a url using javascript

```
function getUrlVars() {
     var vars = {};
     var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
          vars[key] = value;
     });
     return vars;
}
```

Source: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: I like it, but you should remove #anchors at the end:/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&#]*)/gi

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
var start= location.href.indexOf('id=');
var id= location.href.substring(start+ 3, location.length- 1);
```